# Variables in VBA loops

Tags: vba

I'm trying to run a VBA application using a loop and using variables whose names depends on where in the loop I am. Specifically something like

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim varname() As String
while i < 50
varname(i) = asdasd
i = i + 1
Wend
```

Somehow it can't read varname(i) or whatever. It reports subscript out of range.
I have no idea what the problem is, can someone helt me perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your array a capacity first.

```
Sub max()

Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Dim varname() As String
ReDim varname(49) '<---- There

While i < 50
varname(i) = asdasd
i = i + 1
Wend


End Sub
```

This is a good resource for VBA arrays:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164778(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Ah okay. Can I update the ReDim later on, without destroying existing variables? Since the dimension in my actual code will depend on some if outcomes.. So at the start I don't know the final number of variables I'll need.

Comment: yes, the command to use there instead would be `ReDim Preserve`

Comment: I think you can just use `Dim varname(49) as String` without needing `ReDim`.